# Preventing WindowState.Normal

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an application that I am working on *(for myself)*, and I want to prevent the Window from showing at all.

---

So far, what I have got is `WindowState.Minimized` so that the Form's initial state is Minimized. And when I click the app's icon in the Taskbar, I want it to *remain* minimized - not just `Hide()` it when it has shown. So I thought that something like this might work:

```
protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
}
```

But I was wrong. So what I am thinking is that I need something that happends *before* `OnGotFocus`. The reason that just hiding it when it gets focused is not enough, is because you can see, very faintly, that it does actually show itself when you click the icon in the taskbar before `this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimize` gets called.

My only requirement is that the application must not be shown when it's icon is clicked on the Taskbar. I will need to show the window programatically, at some point, though.

How can I make sure that clicking its icon never shows the window?

Comment: Inside 'GotFocus()' event you can hide the form first, then change the WindowState to minimize and then call 'this.Show()' but it will toggle the window icon in the taskbar for that duration.

Comment: Hard to guess why you'd want to do something this unintuitive, of course the machine will fight you.  Just set the Opacity property to 0 to make a window invisible.

Comment: @HansPassant; It just depends on what the application's purpose is. For what this app is to be used for, this will be intuitive.

Comment: Clearly you are ensuring that you won't get a better answer by not explaining this.  SO is not a personal help desk, answers need to be useful to more than one programmer.

Comment: +1 @HansPassant for suggesting 'Opacity'.

Comment: @HansPassant, the accepted (and other) answer(s) will be very helpful for those wanting to do this.

Comment: @Jase this question would benefit from a bit more background as to why you want to do this. The answer shows this is of more interest to others, but explaining your scenario in a bit more detail would help future viewers of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seemed to work for me with no "hint" of it coming and going:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0112)  //WM_SYSCOMMAND
        {
            if ((m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFF0) == 0xF030 ||
                (m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFF0) == 0xF120)
                m.WParam = new IntPtr(0xF020);
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Just override the `WndProc` and this will catch both `SC_MAXIMIZE (0xF030)` and `SC_RESTORE (0x0F120)`.  `SC_MINIMIZE is 0xF020`.

As Hans has suggested, I have edited my post to mask out the low-order bits used by the system per this MSDN section:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: +1 this works perfectly. By the way, do you know what `SC` stands for?

Comment: @KingKing "System Command".  It's a sub-set of message enums linked to the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message.

Comment: You'll need to read the MSDN article for WM_SYSCOMMAND.  Note how it documents how the low 4 bits of wparam are used by the system.  You will need to mask them out.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the form_resize event to trigger windowstate to minimized

```
    private void Form1_Resize ( object sender , EventArgs e )
    {
        if ( WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized )
        {
            // minimize it here
        }
    }
```